# Mapbox: Set zoom level on location found

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox, mapbox-gl

The leaflet documentation tells me that you should use the maxZoom option on location but it's not working (http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-locate-options). When a user is using geolocation on my site and finds their position at the map it zooms in too much and I want to regulate this myself. Does anyone have a quick fix?

Comment: Can you post your site link? to check?

Comment: @Thennarasan https://dabauto.no/verksteder

Comment: In your main.js file there is a line `   var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'mapbox.light').setView([63.51338, 15.03236], 5);` the last parameter `5` is that hardcoded?

if so please change the level of you want and check.

Comment: @Thennarasan yes it's hardcoded. I don't need to change that one, only the zoom when I'm using geolocation..

Comment: Hope that is what you have to modify to regulate the zoom when someone using the geolocation.

Answer (score 0):

in your main.js you have to set a [locate](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-locate-options) option in this section

```
   if (!navigator.geolocation) {
        geolocate.innerHTML = 'Geolocation is not available';
    } else {
        geolocate.onclick = function (e) {
            var tl = new TimelineMax({repeat:2});   
            tl.to("svg.pointwhite", .10, {transformOrigin: "50% 100%", scaleY:0.25, yoyo:true, repeat:1})
              .to("svg.pointwhite", .65, {y:-6, ease:Circ.easeOut, yoyo:true, repeat:1});                   
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            map.locate({ maxZoom: 12}); // locate option goes here       
        };
    }
```